# Difference between form.close and application.exit

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

I am recently out of school, working my first job as a programmer.  We have a user-reported bug that is occurring when our application timeout timer closes the application.  I'm pretty sure I've narrowed it down, but am curious as to why the original programmer would have done this, if it's good coding practice, and if so, I am curious if anyone has a way to handle this.  We are getting a post-closing system error, as it occurs after the main form closes, so we don't get any exception log input.

The close functionality of the timeoutTimer_tick handler does the following:

```
    For iCount As Int16 = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Try
            Application.OpenForms(iCount).Close()
        Catch
        End Try
    Next
    Try
        Application.Exit()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

The program is set with the application property to close when the main form closes (not ALL open forms are closed).  This makes me wonder why we're looping through each form and closing them individually, and then calling Application.Exit()

I'm pretty sure our error is because of the Application.Exit call after all open forms are closed.  It doesn't see the main form, as it was closed during the loop, and throws an error.  I feel like we should be using one or the other, but not both.

Any input or advice?  Which is better, or are either better (or should this code work without error, and I am simply wrong).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In WinForms you have a Shutdown Mode setting (Project Properties>Application Tab)

This allows you to specify `When startup form closes` or `When last form closes`

So logically you should not need `Application.Exit` .If you do then there is some other object hanging around in memory that you need to dispose of (something started on a thread / background worker etc)

So If you have the startup form setting:

```
[StartupFormName].Close
```

or if you have the last form setting:

```
Do While My.Application.OpenForms.Count > 0
    My.Application.OpenForms(0).Close()
Loop
```